# Downloading a file created with POST using GET

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, pdfkit

I'm creating a pdf file in my POST route with `pdfkit`. After that I want to be able to visit my GET route with browser and download the file. Everything works fine as far as I'm using static file name: app creates a pdf and saves it to hard drive. When I visit my route with browser it automatically downloads the file.

The problem is that I want to use dynamic file names. For example when writing data about a car to the pdf file I use this in my POST route:

```
const make = req.body.make;
const model = req.body.model;
const filename = make + model;
---
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`./public/${filename}.pdf`));
```

That works fine, the app creates a pdf with filename combination of make and model.

My first question is, how can access that filename in my GET request? I've tried different kind of approaches but to be honest, I have no clue what I should do. And yes, I know I'm saving the file twice to my hard drive, first with post and then with get.

My goal is to kombine this to the frontend so that user can download the pdf with a click of a button and that leads us to my second question: should I save the file to the database first in my POST request or is there some better way to serve it to the user?

Comment: you can return the filename.

Answer (score -1):

corresponding to "The problem is that I want to use dynamic file names." use "let" instead of "const".

To the question "should I save the file to the database",do not store the file in the database.Instead store the file name and file path in the database.

Call an API with "GET" method with the filename as a param. Inside the API you create function to get the full file path of the file. I think after that you will be able to download.

Comment: Thank you, will try these as soon as I can!